# createOrReplaceInventoryItem replies "Invalid value for ."

Tags: ebay-api

I'm trying to call the createOrReplaceInventoryItem endpoint of the Ebay APIs, but the API response is a 400 error with the description "Invalid value for .", so no fieldName is specified, only a dot.
It worked since friday, I've not changed anything in thi API call. I've tried the API explorer with the Basic example **proposed literally by Ebay**: first of all, the "aspects" region is wrongly written, but also if you remove it (or write it correctly), also the Api Explorer reply with a 400 error "Invalid value for .".

As I said I used the ebay's example into the ebay's tool, I post anyway my own payload, with which I receive the same error.

```
{
    "availability":{
        "shipToLocationAvailability":{
            "quantity":3
        }
    },
    "condition":"NEW",
    "product":{
        "description":"SRED - gr 22",
        "imageUrls":[
            "https://www.wywebsite.it/Images/products/"000.jpg"
        ],
        "title":"Moresilda Red gr 22",
        "ean":[
            "1234567890"
        ],
        "aspects":{
            "Variante":[
                "SRED - gr 22"
            ],
            "Brand":[
                "Blue Fox"
            ]   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: same problem here, have you made any progress?

Comment: I posted on ebay forums, they replied that are checking.. But the problem is from 5 days ago. Ridicoulous

Comment: It's resolved right now

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your `imageUrls` field. It has a double quote inside the value, which is why the input might not be accepted. The URL should end in "`products/000.jpg`" instead of "`products/"000.jpg`". I ran the request myself after making this edit and it returns a 204 Success Code.

Comment: That's an error in my copy-paste. It looks like ebay had an issue on that api call, that is resolved right now